# Android Development - What device are the best and Why?

Tags: android, mobile, tablet

Which devices are the best for development and testing. 
I'm mobile and tablets. Should I stick to the most popular
systems (2.3 mobile, 3.0-3 tablets) or start pointing the 
future devices (4.0)?

Comment: Quite a subjective question, best for what? Best for performance?

Comment: I guess it depends on what features you want to test? Some devices don't have GPS etc.

Comment: that's not a programming question.. shouldn't it be moved to android.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, all of them, because when you develop an application, more real test you can do better it is.

There's nothing like testing with the device in hand. I agree that isn't possible to have all kind of devices, so I suggest to, at least, have a 4.0 device since most of new devices will use this OS version.

But keep in mind there's no perfect device for development/testing.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such 'best devices for testing' in my opinion. You should try to test it in several devices with different screen sizes and from different vendors if you have the possibility, since each vendor usually has a different "flavour" of Android. If this is not possible simply stick to the most popular Tab and Phone and aim at them.

Regarding the platform I would recommend you to develop for 4.0 and try to be compatible with previous versions, this can be hard at times since there are things in ICS that cannot be done or require hard work to be functional in previous versions but it is worth the effort since you will be able to offer your app to most smartphone/tablet owners. Otherwise you are simply reducing the available market for your app.
If you develop and try to be compatible, take a look at the android compatibility library:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Cheers!